# Download canceled due to error: UNKNOWN_IO_ERROR on android (react-native-background-downloader)

Tags: android, react-native

When I download any video using the background downloader, React Native is not working. always showing this error below. How can we solve this problem?

Download cancelled due to error: UNKNOWN_IO_ERROR